# Copy only numeric value from div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make on button click only numeric value should be copied in textbox not character. Any can help me?

HTML

```
<div class="more">
    <div id="dvDistance">
        10 kms
    </div>
    <input type="number" id="firstNumber" />
    <script>
        function copyText() {
            var output = document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("firstNumber").value = output;
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" onClick="copyText();" Value="Multiply" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("firstNumber").value = output.match(/(\d+)/)[1];` or `document.getElementById("firstNumber").value = output.replace(/\D+/g, '');`

Comment: The simplest assuming only leading spaces is `parseInt(output,10)`

Comment: var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerText)

Comment: @Tushar  thanks it worked. Please post it as answer so I vote ur answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expecting only spaces in the value, you can use [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
output.trim()
```

---

You can use regex `\d+` to extract the numeric value from string. `\d+` will match one or more digits.

```
output.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Or, you can also replace non-numeric values from string

```
output.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

---

I'd recommend you to use

1. [Number input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)

   ```
   <input type="number" name="firstNumber" />
   ```
2. [Pattern attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute)

   ```
   <input type="text" name="firstNumber" pattern="\d+" />
   ```

Comment: Your second version would not work if it had _10 disco82_  :P

Comment: @mplungjan You mean _as expected_? Because it gives 1082

Comment: @Tushar :  capturing group can be avoided, `match(/\d+/)[0];`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest assuming only leading spaces is

```
document.getElementById("firstNumber").value = parseInt(output,10);
```

since parseInt will find the number and ignore anything after it

```js
function copyText() {
  var output = document.getElementById("dvDistance").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("firstNumber").value = parseInt(output, 10);
}
```

```html
<div class="more">
  <div id="dvDistance">
    10 kms
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="firstNumber" />
  <input type="button" onClick="copyText();" Value="Multiply" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: _"and ignore anything after it"_. What if there are non-numeric characters at the beginning. Ex. `parseInt('disco82')`. As question is not clear, it's good to go _defensively_ with regex.

Comment: Which is why I added _assuming only leading spaces_

Comment: @Tushar - highly unlikely to find disco82 in a field called distance anyway

Comment: Thanks for your comment, added `trim` in my answer. :P

Answer (score 1):

user parseInt to copy only numeric values .

```js
var a = "10 a";
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = parseInt(a);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```